# Improving Efficiency of my SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have a MySQL table of LIKES (likeID,userID,objectID,likeDate) and I would like to be able to count all the 'likes' that have been made after the user in question.

Typically I would get the date:

```
SELECT likeDate FROM LIKES WHERE userID = <logged in user's ID>
```

and then find all dates and count the row returned (or use mysql COUNT) like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LIKES WHERE likeDate > <given date>
```

However, I'm sure there is a way to do this in one query rather than making two calls to the database. Can anyone help?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Feed the result of the first query directly into the second one:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM LIKES
WHERE likeDate > (
    SELECT max(likeDate)
    FROM LIKES
    WHERE userID = <logged in user's ID>
)
```

However note that you need to add the use of `max()` in your first query.

This query should be the fastest possible way to get your answer. To ensure maximum performance, add indexes on both `userID` and `likeDate`:

```
create index likes_userId on likes(userID);
create index likes_likeDate on likes(likeDate);
```

Comment: Thanks @Bohemian but isn't lc's answer slightly more efficient?

Comment: Absolutely not! His query sucks - his is O(n), mine is O(1). ie his subquery executes oncee for every row in the table! I can't imagine a worse query actually, if it even works.

Comment: For the indexes, it might be better to build two indexes, one on both rows userID, likeDate and one on likeDate. That way you would enable the db to find the max(likeDate) (much) faster

Comment: @Argeman probably, but that's quite a use case specific index, where one on just userid would be more versatile. i would recommend trying all the options and see what works best and balance that with how simple you can keep things

Comment: @Bohemian Your comment is a little harsh considering the OP never qualified they only wanted *one* result. As I read the question, "...and then find all dates and count..." I understood the OP wanted the count of likes after each like date. My query does just that, gives you one count for each date returned in the query in the question. I think you must have just gotten lucky with your ESP.

Comment: @lc even so, you can do what you're suggesting as a join, which is way more efficient than a correlated subquery, which should be avoided like the plague. As an exercise you should change your answer to a join (which I would upvote)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT l1.likeDate, 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM LIKES l2 WHERE l2.likeDate > l1.likeDate) AS likesAfter
FROM LIKES l1
WHERE userID = ?
GROUP BY l1.likeDate
```

Or as a join,

```
SELECT l1.likeDate, COUNT(1)
FROM LIKES l1
LEFT OUTER JOIN LIKES l2 ON l2.likeDate > l1.likeDate
WHERE userID = ?
GROUP BY l1.likeDate
```

Comment: Right there are a few good answers here - any ideas on which is the most efficient???

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM LIKES WHERE likeDate > 
IFNULL((SELECT max(likeDate) FROM LIKES WHERE userID = <logged in user's ID> 
                                  adn  objectId=<question's Id>),0)
and objectId=<question's Id>
```