# Further Improving Efficieny of SQL Query

Tags: mysql, sql

Having got an excellent answer to my last question: [Improving Efficiency of my SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14751541/improving-efficiency-of-my-sql) (thanks @Bohemian) I have now realised I was a little short-sighted as there is an added complication.

Using the same table LIKES (likeID,userID,objectID,likeDate) the idea is that a person earns 1 point each time someone likes an object after they have liked it.

With the help from the previous question I can get the number of likes after a users like but now I need to consider that there are objects in this problem.

I want to be able to calculate the number of points a user is entitled to by counting the likes made after theirs for each object they liked (oooh that was a messy sentence).

I am considering a further "nesting" of SQL but this is out of my league and so I can't really offer any code other than what's in the last question.

Comment: Please add the SQL you're currently using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a correlated subquery:

```
select l.userid, l.objectid, l.LikeDate,
       (select count(*) from likes l2 where l2.objectid = l.objectid and l2.LikeDate >= l.likeDate and l2.userid <> l.userid
       ) as NumLikesAfterward
from likes l
```

What this is doing is counting the number of likes on an object, by other users, after a given like.  It returns one row for every row in `likes`.  The calculation is done using a correlated subquery in the `select` clause.

It will run much faster assuming you have an index on `likes(objectid, likedate, userid)`.

To get the total points for a user:

```
select sum(NumLikesAfterward) as TotalPoints
from (select l.userid, l.objectid, l.LikeDate,
             (select count(*) from likes l2 where l2.objectid = l.objectid and l2.LikeDate >= l.likeDate and l2.userid <> l.userid
             ) as NumLikesAfterward
      from likes l
      where userid = $userid
     ) uol
```

Comment: Appreciate that - I'm gonna trial later tonight and mark as "Answer" if it works.

Comment: Ok tweaked it a little to allow for a userid to be passed into the query and as you said it returns a number of different rows. So would you recommend a simple PHP loop to get the total points?

Comment: @tommyd456 . . . No, I don't think you should do that in PHP.  It is easy and appropriate to do in SQL.

Comment: You're a life saver - i had it working in PHP fine but I like this way more.

Comment: Just wondering whether it's better to avoid a correlated sub-query. Is it possible to use a join instead?

Comment: @tommyd456 . . . These types of correlated subqueries can be written as explicit joins in the `from` clause.  I tend to prefer joins to correlated subqueries, but I happen to think this version is clearer.  By the way, both are doing joins and good database optimizers can optimize this just as well as an explicit join.